# WP, закрыть определенную рубрику от индексации

Tags: wordpress

Какие существуют способы закрыть от индексации поисковиками определенную рубрику/категорию в WP?

Comment: Проще всего через SEO плагин. [How to Noindex Category in Yoast SEO Plugin: WordPress?](https://websamosa.com/how-to-noindex-category-in-yoast-seo/)